# Facebook Marketing API error, You must select an object to promote

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create ads via facebook graph API. I am successfully able to create campaigns, adsets and creatives. When trying to create ads it gives me following error.

```
{"error"=>{"message"=>"Invalid parameter", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>100, "error_subcode"=>1487930, "is_transient"=>false, "error_user_title"=>"You Must Select an Object to Promote", "error_user_msg"=>"Your campaign must include an ad set with a selected object to promote related to your objective (ex: Page, URL, event). Please update your ad set to continue.", "fbtrace_id"=>"BVtDHG2rTNn"}}
```

I made a `POST` call to the endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_XXXXXXX/ads`, with following params:

```
{:name=>"Buy new Item", :object_story_spec=>{:link_data=>{:call_to_action=>{:value=>{}, :type=>"LEARN_MORE"}, :name=>"Buy new Item", :message=>"amazing Items for you", :image_hash=>"7cc87683d1b75492622a82a158790dcb", :link=>"www.xyz.com"}, :page_id=>"123123123"}, :access_token=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Can anyone help me with the problem?

P.S. This [SO question also faces the same problem on PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531018/facebook-ads-sdk-doesnt-allow-to-post-ad-via-api-subcode-1487930)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If yes, pl. help.

Answer (score 3):

This error is also thrown in case when no AdCreative id provided during Ad object creation.

You are trying to post AdCreative params to Ad endpoint.

```
curl \
  -F 'name=My Ad' \
  -F 'adset_id=<AD_SET_ID>' \
  -F 'creative={"creative_id":"<CREATIVE_ID>"}' \
  -F 'status=PAUSED' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads
```